# How does cv::ContourArea() deal with non-closed curves?

Tags: opencv

After using cv::Canny(), it seems that there are some non-closed curves in the image. So my question is, what will cv::ContourArea() deal with them? Counting the area by close the curve first or just ignore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ContourArea](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourArea) reference:

> Calculates the contour area

So it just calculates area (number of pixels if image is discontinuous) of contour.